# MATLAB- Error when trying to plot nested function

Tags: matlab

MATLAB newbie here. I'm trying to make a smooth approximation to the Heaviside function `heaviside(x)`. To that end, I'm doing a standard mollification procedure with a bump function. Here is the nested function `smooth` that I think should carry out the process (I'm sorry if it's an inelegant solution).

`function c = smooth(q,y,e)`
`c = e.^-1*int(igrand(q,y),y,-2,2);`
`igrand(q,y)`

```
function i = igrand(q,y)
i = dbump(q)*heaviside(y);
dbump(q)

    function d = dbump(q)
    d = compose(nbump,quot,x,q);
    nbump(x);
    quot(x,y,e);


        function n = nbump(x)
        n = bump(x)*(ibump(x)).^-1;
        ibump(x)

            function i = ibump(x)
            i = integral(@bump, -2, 2);
            bump(x)

                function b = bump(x)
                region1 = abs(x) < 1;
                b(region1) = (exp(-1./(1 - x(region1).^2)));

                region2 = abs(x) >= 1;
                b(region2) = 0;

        function q = quot(x,y,e)
        q = (x-y)./e;
        end
                end
            end
        end
    end
end
```

`end`

Also, forgive my formatting. The last `end` should be to the left of the preceding one. Also, the definition of `smooth` should be to the left of the rest of the body.

I choose `x = -2:.01:2`, `e = .1` and `syms y real`. However, when I run `plot(x, smooth(q,y,e))`, I get the following error.

`Error using smooth/igrand/dbump/nbump (line 16)`
`Not enough input arguments.`

`Error in smooth/igrand/dbump (line 10)`
       `d = compose(nbump,quot,x,q);`

`Error in smooth/igrand (line 6)`
    `i = dbump(q)*heaviside(y);`

`Error in smooth (line 2)`
`c = e.^-1*int(igrand(q,y),y,-2,2);`

The only error that shows up when I'm actually writing the function is an underline under `quot` near the bottom that says that the function may be unused. But, aren't I composing it with `nbump`?

**Edit**: I've changed `compose(nbump,quot,x,q);` to just `nbump(quot(x,y,e));` and I've changed all of the variables so that they line up (no more q's). Now, when I run `plot(x,smooth(x,y,e))`, it runs for a while, then stalls and gives me the following error messages.

`Error using symengine (line 58)`
`Unable to prove 'abs(10*y + 20) < 1' literally. To test the statement mathematically, use isAlways.`

`Error in sym/subsindex (line 1554)`
                `X = find(mupadmex('symobj::logical',A.s,9)) - 1;`

`Error in sym>privformat (line 2357)`
    `x = subsindex(x)+1;`

`Error in sym/subsref (line 1578)`
            `[inds{k},refs{k}] = privformat(inds{k});`

`Error in bump (line 3)`
`b(region1) = (exp(-1./(1 - x(region1).^2)))`

`Error in smooth/igrand/dbump/nbump (line 16)`
            `n = bump(x)*(ibump(x)).^-1;`

`Error in smooth/igrand/dbump (line 10)`
        `d = nbump(quot(x,y,e));`

`Error in smooth/igrand (line 6)`
    `i = dbump(x,y,e)*heaviside(y);`

`Error in smooth (line 2)`
`s = e.^-1*int(igrand(x,y,e),y,-2,2);`

Comment: I might be wrong, but I don't think compose is as powerful as you think it is.  What happens when you take the semicolon off the compose statement? 
d = compose(nbump,quot,x,q)

Comment: For numerical integration, use [`integral()`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/integral.html) or related (in the see also section)

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, you are calling `nbump` without inputs:

```
Error in smooth/igrand/dbump (line 10)
d = compose(nbump,quot,x,q);
```

Comment: I see. If I want these lines to return the function `nbump(quot(x,y,e))`, what should I use?

Comment: @AlexanderSibelius what do you mean? Just use what you wrote.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to this. I can just write `nbump(quot(x,y,e))` to compose the functions? Maybe I was making this too complicated.

Comment: @AlexanderSibelius Yes.

Comment: Alright, I've done that, but now I'm getting a whole host of new errors that I'll post in an edit.